# Symfony 4: часто сбрасывается авторизация

Tags: сессия, symfony, symfony4

В файле framework.yaml для сессий установлены следующие настройки:

```
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    name: 'prod112'
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax
    cookie_lifetime: 2592000
```

Не смотря на то, что время жизни равно 1 месяцу, где-то спустя полчаса-час выбрасывает из учетной записи, приходится повторно авторизовываться. При этом, кука с этим названием пишется нормально и срок ей указывается соответствующий:

```
prod112 u0cnla99lbgkaaeop2m870k9k4  192.168.117.39  /   2019-12-18T20:12:35.888Z    33  ✓   ✓   Lax
```

При этом, есть аналогичные настройки на dev сервере:

```
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    name: 'dev'
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax
    cookie_lifetime: 2592000
```

Такой проблемы там не наблюдается. Сессии точно пишутся, что в папку дева, что в прод, однако именно на проде в течение 30-60 минут сбрасывается авторизация и требует авторизоваться снова. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: время для кук у вас задано, а как насчет session.gc-maxlifetime ? скорее всего это gc приходит и убивает... (первый раз вижу что бы хотели время жизни сессии месяц)

Comment: Возможно, не совсем сессия нужна, но почему-то на проде не используется кука, в которой данные от авторизации хранятся. Проще говоря, не смотря на наличие куки, приходится авторизовываться каждые полчаса-час, а хотелось бы, что бы авторизация держалась дольше.

Comment: кука для сессии это всего-лишь привязка вашего браузера к серверу (простыми словами) и она никак не влияет на прямую на время жизни сессии. Выше я скинул название опции настройки механизма сессий, прогуглите его или на оф сайте php почитайте, должно прояснить картину.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session:
    gc_maxlifetime: 604800
```

Как и сказал уважаемый @noname2019 время сессии задается параметром `gc-maxlifetime`

В настройках вы можете попросту задать этот параметр для `session` раздела
либо можете непосредственно в `php.ini` изменить параметр  `session.gc-maxlifetime` ежели у вас сессии хранятся в файлах (а они у вас там и хранятся).